# How do I create a mail-enabled public folder in Exchange 2010?

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I've tried to do this but I'm obviously not doing it correctly.  I would just like a folder for certain users and redirect mail from a distribution group into it.  How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using EWS, EWS Managed API, the UI, etc.?

Comment: ECP, but it sounds like from what you're suggesting that I need to enter the EWS portion of the ECP to configure these settings.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Per [Tony Redmond's blog](http://thoughtsofanidlemind.com/2011/02/04/exchange-2010-public-folders-part-1/): "ECP does not have the UI or code to handle public folder management. It has to be done using EMC or EMS." For instructions on creating a public folder using the EMC, go here: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691104(v=exchg.141).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691104%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx). And for instructions on mail enabling it, go here: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997560(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997560%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). Hope that helps.